# How do I call a non-static method from inside a static method?

Tags: spring-mvc, cookies, static, memcached, non-static

I have a utility Cookie class. Which has a getCookie() , trying to call a writetoCache() inside a service implementation class. But inside getCookie(), the writetoCache()  is not being recognized.

This is the getCookie().

```
public static String getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String name, String mse){
//String value = null;
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(cookies != null){
    for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
        if(cookie.getName().equals(name)){
            System.out.println(cookie.getValue());
            System.out.println(cookie.getName());
            System.out.println(cookie.getMaxAge());
            writeToCache(cookie.getName(),cookie.getValue(), 300 );
            return cookie.getValue();
        }
    }
}
return null;
 }
```

This is the writetoCache() inside memcached service class. I am using memcached - `import net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient;`

```
@Override
public void writeToCache(String key, String value, int expiry) {    
    c.set(key, expiry, value);  
}
```

One-way is to create the instance of the non-static method's class in static method's class. But it does not work as there is type mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your *getCookie* is inside the *Cookie* util, than you're not calling the *writeToCache* on memcache client instance rather as s method of *Cookie*. So something's not right there, double check it.

In any case, don't create a new instance, make your memcache client a singleton:

```
private static MemCachedClient mcc = new MemCachedClient("foo");
```

than call the method against the instance:

```
mcc.writeToCache(cookie.getName(),cookie.getValue(), 300 );
```